# Windows 7 non-admin user start or stop a particular service

Tags: windows-7

I am using windows 7 professional edition. I have installed oracle 11g in my laptop for education/learning purpose. Though the oracle service is not required always and it make my system busy. I want to stop the service and start it when required. I always run windows in non-admin user/normal user mode which don't allow me to start/stop the oracle services.

Is there any way to start/stop a service in windows 7 as a normal user/non-admin user.

Thanks.
Shahidul

Answer (score 0):

Run cmd as admin and run

> net start

This will return a list of services that are running.

> Adobe Acrobat Update Service
>
> AMD External Events Utility
>
> Apple Mobile Device
>
> etc...

Find the service you want to stop and run

> net stop "service name"

When you want to start it, just run

> net start "service name"

You can always write a batch file to do this also and then run it as administrator.